Missed the application deadline for a TA job. Should I contact them?
I missed the application deadline for a TA job by a day.
How should I contact the hiring committee while still looking professional and not make it awkward for anyone? Any suggestions?
The reason behind missing it is that I discovered it shortly before the deadline.

To answer the question in the title: there is no harm in contacting them in a humble and professional way to ask if they would accept a late application.
Whether they will is likely to depend on the rules of their institution (they may not be allowed to) and on whether they have good candidates already.
For the question in the body, of how to ask, this advice largely applies: be short and to the point.
Don't forget to mention why you are late. Try to contact an academic rather than HR if you can, eg if the job ad has "contact Dr Smith for informal enquiries" or similar, or if you know somebody involved in the process.

I would immediately apply, provided any application system is still active, and also contact them directly asking for consideration. If the system is now closed, I'd provide the material necessary for the application in the request for consideration.
Whether this is successful or not may depend on rules, as Flyto states, but it might depend more on whether they application pool is over or under subscribed. Universities need a certain number of TAs to manage the undergraduate program in many fields. In math it is a lot of people and things get hard to manage if there are too few.
It is probably enough to present your case as you do here. It is worth the effort and not applying or requesting an exception wins you nothing.
If your application to the doctoral (I assume) program is strong, they might be especially interested in making exceptions, budget permitting.

I strongly second the "immediately" part. It's not a question of etiquette; it's a question of whether there are still positions available. (And even as far as etiquette is concerned, telling them now while they still have time to process the applications is more polite than the most carefully worded message you might deliver when they're almost done.)
